# TYPO3 - indexed_search - crawler cofiguration - multilanguage site

Tags: typo3, multilingual, tx-indexed-search

I want to disable frontend indexing an make use of crawler. How to setup a crawler configuration for:

A) indexing the pagetree in several languages

B) indexing custom records in several languages

But there is nothing menitoned regarding languages in the documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/indexed_search/IndexingConfigurations/CrawlerSetup/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexed search always uses frontend indexing. It only varies whether any visitor calls your page or if the crawler calls the page. Each time the cache is filled (by the first call) the content gets indexed.

The language configuration can be found in the manual:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/crawler/ExtCrawler/Configuration/ConfigurationRecords/Index.html (see the field 'Configuration') or the next page where `paramSets.[key]` gets described.

Be aware of any settings of the Url-parameter `L`, which is used as *the* language parameter for TYPO3.

Comment: Had already found this, too. But on 8.7 LTS, there seems to be no EXT:crawler anymore...? Is it integrated into EXT:indexed_search and configuration is the same?

Comment: I've got a better solution for this: If the page already has a valid automatically generated xml-sitemap (and it should!) including extension records, better crawl this sitemap by wget. This prevents redundant configuration for custom records, languages etc in several places (sitemap + crawler). Example: "wget --quiet https://www.domain.tld/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "https?://[^<]+" | wget -i -"